# Testing Sencha touch 2 apps

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, sencha-touch-2

I'm looking for best practices to test Sencha Touch 2 apps. ideally, i would like to automate the execution of test sets (Via CI for example).

I've Looked for test frameworks like Jasmine, JSTestdriver. There is not a lot of feedback about using those frameworks with ST2.

Any ideas ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704665/how-to-test-a-sencha-2-app

Answer (score 0):

To test my Sencha Touch application, I use Ruby with the gems Cucumber and Capybara.

It basically allows you click through the application.

Here's basically how to set up your environment. It says 'on windows' but it works as well on mac.

http://www.richardlawrence.info/2011/08/20/getting-started-with-ruby-cucumber-and-capybara-on-windows/

You can download a starter project at the end of the article.