# How to test a Sencha 2 app?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I cant see any "how to test a Sencha 2 app" in the documentation - is there really no framework support for testing? How should one test a Sencha 2 app, whats best pratice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your app under local server like wampserver, apache tomcat etc.

Be sure to use Web browsers like Chrome, Safari only which supports Webtk engine.

Comment: Once you manage to load it up in chrome, get "Ripple Mobile Emulator" in the chrome webstore. Its great, lets you simulate accelerometer behaviour etc. http://ripple.tinyhippos.com/

Comment: ^ +1 for fake device testing :)

Comment: hmm, see see. Seems like no easy way to do it, has to be something between unit testing with Jasmine and running selenium tests with my Tomcat server which again runs a in-memory database with given state. A bit strange Sencha havent a recommended and well-thought way of testing the apps written in that framework.

Answer (score 1):

found a good Sencha blog about testing:

http://www.sencha.com/blog/automating-unit-tests/

Comment: also see this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820363/using-selenium-to-test-sencha-2-app

Answer (score 1):

Here's a 5 part series covering unit testing using Jasmine (used internally by Sencha) and integration testing using Siesta (built for Sencha app level testing).

- http://pivotallabs.com/sencha-touch-bdd-part-1/ - Jasmine unit testing
- http://pivotallabs.com/sencha-touch-bdd-part-2/ - Unit testing models.
- http://pivotallabs.com/sencha-touch-bdd-part-3/ - Testing Views and Mocking Stores
- http://pivotallabs.com/sencha-touch-bdd-part-4/ - Headless testing using PhantomJS
- http://pivotallabs.com/sencha-touch-bdd-part-5/ - Controller testing.

Comment: If you're doing ExtJS you might also want to look at http://GluJS.com that includes some cool testing stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As referenced in the comment links... the best way to do it is to run it localhost. I use xampp to do this. You need to also install Sencha SDK tools, etc. You can find the official guide on how to setuo your application for testing using sencha command here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/command

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a Rails architecture with Cucumber, Capybara and Selenium to to tests your Sencha Touch 2 web application. This is working pretty well for me.