# Using Selenium to test Sencha 2 app

Tags: selenium, sencha-touch-2

I cant click on a Sencha 2 generated button as it isnt a input field. It builds up the button with divs and spans.

Found this link which describes how to click the buttons with a Selenium test
http://mobilewebqa.blogspot.com/

Problem: How to click on a Sencha Touch button?  The built in Selenium click, click_at, etc methods would not work.

Solution: Fake out a Sencha Touch tap event by using the following steps:

```
focus
mouse_down
mouse_up
```

But how do I invoke this events from Selenium?

Any other good advice how to test the UI is received with thanks. I saw someone mentioned Siesta, anyone used that?

http://www.bryntum.com/products/siesta/

Comment: Siesta would make this easy: t.click('>>button') will click the component matching the button xtype (component query used). You can try the samples, which include 8 or so ST examples.

Comment: Read briefly about Siesta, seems like a more appropriate tool for testing Sencha apps, will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute Javascript via Selenium. So you're able to use Ext.ComponentQuery.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("var button = 
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mypanel button')[0]; 
button.fireEvent('tap',button)");
```

This is not pretty but works.

Comment: hmm, I liked this!  Ugly, but still, I will give it a try

Answer (score 1):

This is the step I use to simulate a tap on a button, but we're using Capybara, RSpec and Selenium :

```
page.find("span", :text => Regexp.new(THE_BUTTON_LABEL)).click
```

Hope you can make something out of it...

Comment: cool, thanks we reply, I Google Capybara and RSpec, looks like Ruby specific things.

Based on your syntax it seems like the click event is registered in the span which Sencha 2 generates

Answer (score 0):

You must find some way of directing Selenium to the button in Question.

Using a regular expression would work, but I believe it would be best to add attributes to the button as it makes it more obvious what is going on.

With the browser addon you can press record, then go back and choose from a dropdown of the criteria that Selenium selects by.